# excel dynamic moving range of 12 months

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

[image]What I am stating here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.

I have a table (Table 1) in a excel spreadsheet, which contains a date column from Jan 2017 to Dec 2020 (actuals + forecast) and a revenue column corresponding to those dates. I have another table (Table 2) which contains 1 year of data points which is updated every month. For the current month, it has from May 2017 to Apr 2018. For the next month, I will updated it to show from Jun 2017 to May 2018. I would like to simplify this process by using index match and offset function. I envision having to just update the current month field in a separate cell and table 2 would automatically update the 12 months of data point. Any ideas on how it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Please next time give a full example so we do not waste time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid OFFSET as it is a volatile formula, but use INDEX/MATCH to set the range:

```
INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)+12)
```

This assumes that the dates are in column A and the Data you want returned is in Column B:B with the start date in G1.

You would use this any where you would use the range,  For Ex:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)+12))
```

[image]

Or if you just want to return the number N months from the start, then do something like this:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($G2,$A:$A,0)+N)
```

Change the N to the number of months from the desired that you want.

[image]

And now that you have shown what you intend:

For the list of Months:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)>$F$3,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH($E$3,$A:$A,0)+ROW(1:1)-1))
```

For the number:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)>$F$3,"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH($E$3,$A:$A,0)+ROW(1:1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. I have added a picture of what I am trying to achieve. your solution appear to be close but I am not quite there yet with that. Do you know how I can achieve what I have posted up there?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works. I am also researching how to use name ranges to achieve the same thing.